# What type of connector is this? Where can I get a new one and a cable around 2metres long for it with 20 strands inside?

Tags: connector, cables

For reference: I am incredibly new to electronics.

The attached photo is of a cable that connects two halves of a split keyboard I just bought. My hope was that this cable would have been 4 wires or something which I would have been able to desolder it to extend the cable length. But instead I find this 20 wire cable connecting both halves with the connector on the end.

So now I am thinking maybe this may be a standard type connector and a standard type of cable I may be able to find online instead of having to do a bunch of soldering with very tiny wires. Any thoughts on how to proceed? Maybe where to find that type of connector and a 20 strand cable in the 2 metre range?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you tried contacting the keyboard manufacturer?

Comment: No I'm pretty much hacking their keyboard, not sure if they'd try to be helpful.

Comment: Its an off the shelf connector but you are unlikely to find a custom cable made with said connector and arbitrary cable size and orientation. It may not be one to one on each side.

Comment: What is the off the shelf connector called? Can I find a 20 strand cable and a way to affix the cable strands to the connector?

Comment: Probably made by JST or a copy. Look at their online catalogs. You can get 20 strand cable, then you have to get a crimper and crimps for the JST connector.

Comment: depending on the kind of signals that are present in this cable, extending it to 2 metres may result in errors

Comment: a picture like the one that you posted is not enough to positively identify the connector. ... it is like posting a picture of an end view of a screw with the screwdriver slot being shown, and asking to identify the type of screw

Comment: @jstola I can post the other angles with measurements later today when I get home. If I measure the voltage on the wires can you tell em if extending it to 2m would be a problem?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams guess what they have a 187cm long replacement! Thanks for the out of the box suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams pointed out, the manufacturer had a replacement cable so I'm safe. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Time to take out the soldering iron and get some soldering practice. Cut each conductor a bit staggered from the next and splice in an extension. If you are new to electronics you will soon find that you need to lean how to solder anyway.

Good luck